# installing html.py package on mac osx

Tags: python, installation

I am trying to install a package html.py on mac osx.  I downloaded the package, HTML.py-0.04, and now it sits in my downloads folder. What do I have to do next to have python recognize this package?  I am using python 3.5.  Incidentally, when I tried to open the file HTML.py with idle and run it I get invalid syntax on the first print line. It looks like the developer didn't put parenthesis around the print statement. Maybe this module isn't for python 3.5. Would it still work in 3.5 if installed properly?

Answer (score 0):

You're asking a lot of questions there.

To install the package you need to unzip the file, navigate to inside the directory in the Terminal (using `cd`, google how to do this if you don't know), then call `python setup.py install` to install the package. This is described in the `README.txt` file that is distributed in the package; a very good place to start.

If you run into trouble then it may not be compatible with your python version.